# Confusion about Boltzmann distribution

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

It is well-known that the Boltzmann distribution is given by $p\propto e^{-E/kT}$, where $E$ refers to the energy.

A standard textbook problem is to find the pressure variation in a rotating cylinder using Boltzmann distribution.

Working in the rotating frame, integrating the centrifugal force gives a potential energy $U(r)=-\frac{1}{2}m r^2 \omega^2$, which gives us a boltzmann distribution of $e^{mr^2\omega^2/2kT}$.

However, a contradiction seemingly arises if we were to analyse the same problem in the lab frame. In the lab frame, particles at a radius $r$ from the centre would have kinetic energy of $\frac{1}{2}m (r\omega)^2$, giving a boltzmann distribution of $e^{-mr^2\omega^2/2kT}$ which obviously does not agree with the result derived in the rotating frame of reference (with an additional minus sign in the exponent).

Why is this the case?

Comment: Can you please provide a reference?

Comment: Please take a look at Example 3 and Problem 15 of this handout : https://knzhou.github.io/handouts/T1Sol.pdf @TobiasFünke

Comment: Given the website address, I guess that you should ask @knzhou for a hint! :-) Also related (no answer to date): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/83167/226902.

Comment: This apparent discrepancy arises from the difference in the form of energy considered in each frame. In the rotating frame, the potential energy term contributes an additional factor to the Boltzmann distribution, leading to a different functional form. However, both expressions are consistent within their respective frames of reference and describe the statistical distribution of particles in their respective energy states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Boltzman distribution for a system that that is in equilibrium in with a frame rotating at angular velocity ${\boldsymbol\omega}$, but whose energy $H$  is being observed  in the lab frame is
$$
\propto e^{-\beta(H-{\boldsymbol \omega}\cdot {\bf  L})}
$$
where ${\bf L}$ is the angular momentum.  Similarly for a system in equilibrium with a frame moving at velocity ${\bf v}$ we have
$$
\propto e^{-\beta(H- {\bf p}\cdot {\bf v})},
$$
where ${\bf p}$ is the system's momentum. I don't have a reference for this, but it is pretty standard.

Comment: Could you please provide a more detailed explanation, perhaps on the derivation of the equations?  If possible, please provide a reference (maybe a textbook) where I can read up more about this. Thank you!

Comment: The distribution $\rho$ in phase space  is derived by requiring that the entropy $s=-\int \rho \ln \rho d\Gamma$ is maximum subject to the constraints $\int \rho d\Gamma=1$ (probability adds to unity) , $E=\int \rho H d\Gamma$, and $L= \int \rho (r\times p)d\Gamma$. We introduce lagrange multipliers $\alpha$, $\beta$( $\equiv 1/kT$), and $\omega$ to enforce the constraints.  This must be in Landau and Lifshitz somewhere, but my copy is at the office.

Comment: @bob the legend Found it in  Landau and Lifshitz "Statistical Physics" (2nd ed)  pages 99 to 100. Eqs 34.2 and 34.3.  Online at https://ia800702.us.archive.org/22/items/ost-physics-landaulifshitz-statisticalphysics/LandauLifshitz-StatisticalPhysics.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The contradiction between considering the system in non-inertial and laboratory reference frames in this case is apparent. Due to the fact that the part of the consideration related to the inertial system is incorrect to a greater extent.

The application of the Boltzmann distribution is correct for systems that are in equilibrium in inertial reference frames. The Boltzmann distribution, which takes into account the forces of inertia, is probably *approximately* true for stationary states of systems in weakly non-inertial reference frames when the accelerations are small. Hence the well-known solution to the problem of the density of an ideal gas inside a rotating cylinder. But in a laboratory frame of reference, the stationary state of a system with moving parts at the boundary and flows of matter inside is a nonequilibrium state. The Boltzmann distribution for the system as a whole is not applicable in such a situation. Local equilibrium, of course, takes place. Accordingly, the velocity distribution for gas molecules in the laboratory frame of reference depends on the point of the system and has the form
$$
w({\bf v}|{\bf r}) = \left(\frac{m}{2\pi kT}\right)^{3/2}\exp\left(-\frac{m}{2kT}\left({\bf v}-{\bf v}_0({\bf r})\right)^2\right)
$$
where ${\bf v}_0({\bf r}) = {\bf \omega \times r}$.

A real almost ideal gas has a low but non-zero viscosity. Therefore, I think that the realistic scenario for the processes occurring in the system under consideration is as follows. Gas, different layers of which move at different speeds, will slow down the cylinder. To maintain a stationary state, energy will have to be expended, which will be dissipated in the form of heat and the gas will heat up, although probably quite slowly. At this stage, the picture becomes more complex, and we see that the stationary state is not entirely stationary and the problem requires further consideration. So, in my opinion, the generally accepted solution to the problem under discussion is a zero approximation to the consideration of the processes occurring in such a nonequilibrium system.

Comment: what is $\mathbf{v}$ in the equation? Is $\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{v_0}$ supposed to represent some relative velocity? If yes, may I know why this is the case? Also, could you please explain how boltzmann distribution would change based on the reference frame (i.e. inertial vs accelerating), thank you!

Comment: @bobthelegend ${\bf v}$ is the velocity of a gas particle in the lab frame, ${\bf v-v_0}$ is the velocity of this particle in the rotating frame. If you think that an ideal gas in a rotating frame obeys the Boltzmann distribution, then you have the ordinary Maxwell distribution for ${\bf v - v_0}$, and for ${\bf v}$ you have a shifted Maxwell distribution accordingly.

Comment: @bobthelegend I have doubts that an analogue of the Boltzmann distribution exists for highly non-inertial frames. Mike Stone's answer contains references to Landau. In my answer I wrote that I think this approach is an approximation. The forces of inertia are not limited to centripetal force. I don’t understand, for example, how the recipe from Landau’s book takes into account the Coriolis force, which acts on gas particles in a non-inertial reference frame and, generally speaking, for not too large $\omega$ can be significantly greater than the centripetal force.

Comment: @Gec  Coriolis acts rather like a magnetic field, and Niels Bohr famaouly pointed out that a magnetic field did NOT affect the equilibrium of a classical Boltzmann gas. It does have an effect on quantum systems (Landau levels) and Coriolis also has a quantum-system effect (The chiral vortical effect)

Comment: @mikestone I like the analogy between Coriolis and Lorentz forces. Do you have any suggestions on what to do about the fact that equilibrium in a rotating frame looks like nonequilibrium in a laboratory frame? The movement of layers of a medium at different speeds implies non-zero momentum flux and, therefore, viscosity and friction between layers in a laboratory system.

Comment: Once you are in equilibrium with the rotating container, the system is rotating as one body and  there is no more friction. It is friction that *gets* you rotating with the moving frame/container. This subject is much studied for rotating superfluids.

Answer (score 0):

This question relates to the pressure arising from the motions of particles in an ideal gas. The particles have no contact with the cylinder apart from the wall at the outer boundary. Thus, they do not acquire the tangential velocity of a segment of a rigid rotating cylinder at their radius (as measured in the lab frame), which seems to be what you were assuming in your question, and which led to the contradiction.